# How to mix annotations with faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Using JBoss 6.0.0.Final, Richfaces 3.3.3.Final, MyFaces 2.0.6, facelets 1.1.15.B1 (a limitation of RF 3).

I'm on a legacy project which contains hundreds of beans defined in `faces-config.xml`. I'd like to keep those defined in faces-config.xml but use annotations for new beans. However, when I've tried this I've not had success. The beans defined by annotation  i.e.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Foobar implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

The bean is not accessible from my JSF page. I believe I've specified the 2.0 version in my faces-config.xml by using the proper header.

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

Is there anything else I need to do in the `faces-config.xml` to allow annotations to also be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Annotated beans will fail in the following cases:

1. `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` is not declared to conform to JSF 2.0.
2. `@ManagedBean` is of `javax.annotation` package instead of `javax.faces.bean`.
3. Bean class is not been compiled/built into WAR's `/WEB-INF/classes`.
4. Bean is packaged in a JAR file which is missing `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`.
5. A wrong managed bean name is being used in EL, it should be the bean class name with 1st character lower cased according Javabeans spec. So in your particular example, `#{fooBar}` should work, but `#{FooBar}` won't.
6. Webapp is *actually* using JSF 1.x libs (you can read JSF version in server startup log).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm not trying to use both annotation and faces-config.xml configuration for the same bean. I want to add new beans without having to migrate old beans off of using faces-config.xml